# Best arranging Foundation 5 projects

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I am sorry it sounds a bit silly to be asking this, but I want the best way to do it. So my problem is :

I am working with Foundation 5 for the very first time, I installed it using Grunt & Libsaas. Now when I have everything ready, the size of this whole folder is now 32MB. What are the necessary files that I need to Deploy on the server.

Here is my file structure : [image]

And if I am working with 3 projects using Foundation, is there a way to have COMMON FILES (Files that need not be deployed on server for the project to work, e.g node_modules etc) at one centralized location, & only the necessary files go into the project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to place on the server the compiled css and js

Comment: Thanks @Elise, But do I need to have node_modules & some other grunt files in every project ? Isn't there someway to keep them one place, & use it in all my projects from one centralized location?